# Unable to call controller method from js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("mapchanged")]
public ActionResult mapchanged(string latitud, string longitud)
{
  Session["Latitude"] = latitud;
  Session["Longitude"] = longitud;
  return RedirectToAction("search?what=&by=bnm");
}
```

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  url: url, // '@Url.Action("mapchanged")',
  data: {
    latitud: map.getCenter().lat(),
    longitud: map.getCenter().lng()
  },
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    alert('Success');
  },
  error: function(err) {
    alert('error = ' + err.status);
  }
});
```

The above code is not working - it's giving error 404. Also tried `var url = '"Home/mapchanged/"'` but it's also not working. The ajax code is in map.js file.

Comment: What's the full URL being requested?  What action method on what controller are you expecting to be reached and why?

Comment: I am trying to load multiple markers in map while map dragged or moved. Controller name : 'Home', action is : 'mapchanged'.

Comment: So which request is returning a 404 error?  What is the URL for that request and what controller action do you expect that URL to reach?  It looks like you're making two requests here, one to `mapchanged` and one to `search`.  You have to find out which one is failing.

Comment: Side note: `async: false` is a bad idea.  Your browser is probably giving you a warning about it on the console.  Browsers are likely to stop supporting it if they haven't already, and its use is contrary to JavaScript patterns and practices.

Comment: I removed "return RedirectToAction("search?what=&by=bnm");", and marked an breakpoint at begining at "mapchanged" but my control is not hitting the break point.

Comment: You really need to provide a more complete description of the problem.  In your current code, what is the value of `url`?  In your browser's debugging tools, what is the full and complete URL being requested?  What is the server's response?  If that URL is resulting in a 404 error, why specifically do you think it shouldn't?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a view for that action? Plus it's an ajax post, you can't redirect to another action while doing ajax post. Try to return json from that action and see if it works.

```
return Json(new { true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce source code. It had some issues with current code.

Missed configure for Route attribute at RouteConfig class, **without this configure [Route] annotation/attribute not work.**

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()
```

In ajax call did not use JSON.stringify for data

```
 var data = {
       latitud: map.getCenter().lat(),
       longitud: map.getCenter().lng()
    };
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: '@Url.Action("mapchanged")',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Success');
        window.location.href = data.url;
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert('error = ' + err.status);
    }
});
```

You should return Json object with url property instead of RedirectToAction

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("mapchanged")]
        public ActionResult mapchanged(LongLat obj)
        {
            Session["Latitude"] = obj.latitud;
            Session["Longitude"] = obj.longitud;
            //return RedirectToAction("search?what=&by=bnm");
            return Json(new {url = "search?what=&by=bnm"});
        }

        public class LongLat
        {
            public double latitud { get; set; }
            public double longitud { get; set; }
        }
```